# Erro ao usar o terminal do Pycharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm

Ao começar a aprender o framework Django tive o seguinte problema:

No momento estou usando a ide pycharm community por recomendações, e fiz toda a instalação do Django através do PIP, so que me acontece que se eu acessar o meu projeto pelo pycharm não consigo rodar os comando do Django como pode ver na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém se eu acesso o projeto inicial do pycharm que ele mesmo criou, apenas criei alguns arquivo, ele já me deixa executar normalmente:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e agora vem o pior, se eu acessando este projeto do pycharm eu mando o comando para mudar o caminho via terminal ele também executa

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja só não executa se abrir o ambiente do projeto de fato. Isso esta me prejudicando pois preciso deixar duas telas abertas.

OBS: já tentei executar pelo cmd, mas o comando Django não funciona de nenhuma forma acessando as pastas.

Gostaria de saber se alguém já teve algum problema do tipo e o que posso fazer para ajustar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Está faltando "ativar" o ambiente virtual que foi feita a instalação do Django, antes de executar os comandos associados àquele ambiente virtual.

A IDE Pycharm funciona por padrão com o ambiente virtual ativo. Isso faz com que todas as instalações fiquem associadas àquele ambiente que está executando na IDE.

Para ter acesso ao Django instalado no mesmo ambiente da IDE, basta "ativar" o ambiente virtual que o Pycharm criou.

Você pode tentar descobrir o diretório de onde está esse ambiente virtual (da IDE) e ativar esse ambiente no terminal do Windows antes de executar o comando `django-admin`.

### No ambiente da IDE

Para descobrir o caminho de execução do binário do Python da IDE, faça o seguinte:

execute o comando:

```
python
import sys

print(sys.executable)
```

### No terminal (fora da IDE)

Sabendo qual o caminho do executável, agora é só "ativar" o ambiente virtual com o seguinte comando:

```
<diretório-do-executavel>\Scripts\activate
```

Após executar estes passos, será possível executar o comando `django-admin`.

É possível saber que o ambiente virtual está "ativo" porque vai aparecer uma indicação com uma espécie de prefixo com `(nome-do-ambiente)` no shell/bash/cmd.

powershell

[image: venv cmd]

cmd

[image: venv cmd2]